# Как редактировать красиво через xml? нужно вставить картинки и текст

Tags: android

Я первый раз работаю в андроид студии, подскажите пожалуйста, правильно ли я думаю?
Вот тут я начинаю размещать различные блоки: текст, картинки и прочее. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я беру textView, размещаю, меняю шрифт, усатнеавливаю отсупы и прочее, затем перехожу в strings.xml и пишу там

```
<string name="head_str">
    </string>
```

В xml, там где устанавливала текстовы блок, в парамере text пишу следующее: @string/head_str

Правильно? А в файле string заполняю текстом? Что я еще забыла?
Еще вопрос по заполнению текста, слышала, что можно сделать через html теги, есть какие-то ресурсы, где быстро можно сделать html текст?

Comment: В правом верхнем углу переключите режим в `Code`, тогда вы сможете верстать экран путем написания кода XML.

Comment: Пробуйте верстать в XML по канонам андроид. Не советую возиться с HTML в андроид, с ним будет гора проблем, это неправильный путь.

Comment: то есть мне не через string делать? А как писать через код в xml?

Comment: Да, все правильно. Для картинок используйте ImageView, для текста TextView. Вот пример верстки экрана, анимированый гайд с уроками от гугл:   https://developer.android.com/codelabs/constraint-layout#0 .  Использовать HTML форматирования, как и сказали выше, чаще всего совершенно излишне. Все решается несколькими TextView и ImageView с нужными атрибутами и их взаиморазмещением. Можно 
еще  ознакомиться с ресурсами по верстке: http://material.io